How to align partial width column to right side of container with tailwind
I have a section that extends beyond the page on either side and need to reduce the width of the column containing text for smaller screens. I reduced it to 70% and it works great on the right half, but aligns left and the left side, causing it to fall off the screen. I have tried a number of modifications, but cannot get the reduced width column to align right. Any help is appreciated!


<style>
    @import url("https://use.typekit.net/poz1xqv.css");
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syne:wght@400..800&display=swap');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap')
    *
    {
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
    }
    .body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .syne-font {
      font-family: "Syne", sans-serif;
      font-optical-sizing: auto;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-style: normal;
    }
    .work-sans-light {
      font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
      font-optical-sizing: auto;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-style: normal;
    }
    .work-sans-medium {
      font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
      font-optical-sizing: auto;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-style: normal;
    }
    .cta-button {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 0;
      /*border: 2px solid black;*/
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .cta-button:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      /*background-color: black;
      color: white;*/
    }
    .cta-button::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      border-top: 2px solid black;
      border-left: 2px solid black;
      transition: ease .5s;
    }
    .cta-button::after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
      transition: ease .5s;
    }
    .cta-button:hover::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      border-top: 2px solid black;
      border-left: 2px solid black;
      transition: ease .5s;
    }
    .cta-button:hover::after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0px;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
      transition: ease .5s;
    }
    .more-button {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      width: 60%;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 0;
      /*border: 2px solid black;*/
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      /*opacity: .5;*/
      transition: opacity 1s, background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .more-button:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      /*background-color: black;
      color: white;*/
    }
    .more-button::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      border-top: 2px solid black;
      border-left: 2px solid black;
      transition: ease .5s;
    }
    .more-button::after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
      transition: ease .5s;
    }
    .more-button:hover::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      border-top: 2px solid black;
      border-left: 2px solid black;
      transition: ease .5s;
    }
    .more-button:hover::after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0px;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
      transition: ease .5s;
    }
    .hidden-text {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: relative;
      opacity: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 1s ease;
    }
    .hidden-text:hover {
      opacity: 100;
    }
    .feature-image:hover ~ .hidden-text,
    .hidden-text:hover {
      opacity: 100;
    }
    .sliding-section {
      /* margin-left: -120px;
      margin-right: 120px; */
      min-height: 800px;
      position: relative;
      margin-left: -25%;
      margin-right: 25%;
      /*width: 120%;*/
      width: 150%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      transform: translateX(0);
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
      .sliding-section {
        width: 120%;
        margin-left: -10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
      }
    }
    .residential {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 600px;
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 1;
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .residential:hover {
      transform: translateX(10%);
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .residential:hover ~ .commercial{
      transform: translateX(10%);
      opacity: .25;
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .hidden-button {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .residential:hover .hidden-button{
      opacity: 1;
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .commercial:hover .hidden-button{
      opacity: 1;
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .commercial {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 600px;
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 1;
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .commercial:hover {
      transform: translateX(-10%);
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .commercial:hover ~ .residential{
      transform: translateX(-10%);
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .residential:has(~.commercial:hover) {
      transform: translateX(-10%);
      opacity: .25;
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .hid-text-res {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: relative;
      opacity: 100;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 1s ease;
    }
    .hid-text-com {
      opacity: 100;
      transition: 1s ease;
    }
    .hid-text-com:has(~.residential:hover) {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script>
    tailwind.config = {
      theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
            'TradeGothicNext': ['"Trade Gothic Next"', 'sans-serif']
          },
          fontFamily: {
            'Syne': ['"Syne"', 'sans-serif']
          },
          fontFamily: {
            'Work Sans': ['"Work Sans"', 'sans-serif']
          },
      colors: {
        greybg: '#CECCC4',
      }
          transitionDuration: {
            '300': '300ms',
          }
    }
      }
    }
  </script>

<div class="sliding-section w-screen mx-auto">
  <div class="w-full grid grid-cols-2 gap-5 md:gap-10">
    <div class="residential feature-image">
      <img class="object-cover overflow-x-visible" src="https://danverstg.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/img4.jpg" alt="Residential" />
      <h3 class="hid-text-com text-right syne-font pt-4">Multi-Family</h3>
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 max-md:pl-5 max-md:w-[70%]">
        <div class="hidden-button flex items-center justify-center max-md:order-2 max-md:mt-5"><a href="#" class="more-button work-sans-medium">learn more</a></div>
        <div class="max-md:order-1">
          <p class="hid-text-com text-right work-sans-light pt-4">See our wide variety of cabinet types and styles and how they can accommodate all of your outdoor kitchen needs</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="commercial">
      <img class="object-cover overflow-x-visible" src="https://danverstg.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/img5.jpg" alt="Commercial" />
      <h3 class="hid-text-com text-left syne-font pt-4">Hospitality</h3>
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 max-md:pr-5 max-md:w-[70%]">
        <div class="hid-text-com hidden-text"><p class="hid-text2 text-left work-sans-light pt-4">See our wide variety of cabinet types and styles and how they can accommodate all of your outdoor kitchen needs</p></div>
        <div class="hidden-button flex items-center justify-center max-md:mt-5"><a href="#" class="more-button work-sans-medium">learn more</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




You could consider applying margin-left: auto via the ml-auto class to the text container so that it is pushed and aligned to the right.


@import url("https://use.typekit.net/poz1xqv.css");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syne:wght@400..800&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap') * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.syne-font {
  font-family: "Syne", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}

.work-sans-light {
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

.work-sans-medium {
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

.cta-button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  /*border: 2px solid black;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.cta-button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*background-color: black;
      color: white;*/
}

.cta-button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  transition: ease .5s;
}

.cta-button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  transition: ease .5s;
}

.cta-button:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  transition: ease .5s;
}

.cta-button:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  transition: ease .5s;
}

.more-button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  /*border: 2px solid black;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  /*opacity: .5;*/
  transition: opacity 1s, background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.more-button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*background-color: black;
      color: white;*/
}

.more-button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  transition: ease .5s;
}

.more-button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  transition: ease .5s;
}

.more-button:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  transition: ease .5s;
}

.more-button:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  transition: ease .5s;
}

.hidden-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.hidden-text:hover {
  opacity: 100;
}

.feature-image:hover~.hidden-text,
.hidden-text:hover {
  opacity: 100;
}

.sliding-section {
  /* margin-left: -120px;
      margin-right: 120px; */
  min-height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  /*width: 120%;*/
  width: 150%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: ease 1s;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .sliding-section {
    width: 120%;
    margin-left: -10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
}

.residential {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 600px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.residential:hover {
  transform: translateX(10%);
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.residential:hover~.commercial {
  transform: translateX(10%);
  opacity: .25;
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.hidden-button {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.residential:hover .hidden-button {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.commercial:hover .hidden-button {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.commercial {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 600px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.commercial:hover {
  transform: translateX(-10%);
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.commercial:hover~.residential {
  transform: translateX(-10%);
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.residential:has(~.commercial:hover) {
  transform: translateX(-10%);
  opacity: .25;
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.hid-text-res {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.hid-text-com {
  opacity: 100;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.hid-text-com:has(~.residential:hover) {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease 1s;
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script>
  tailwind.config = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        fontFamily: {
          'TradeGothicNext': ['"Trade Gothic Next"', 'sans-serif']
        },
        fontFamily: {
          'Syne': ['"Syne"', 'sans-serif']
        },
        fontFamily: {
          'Work Sans': ['"Work Sans"', 'sans-serif']
        },
        colors: {
          greybg: '#CECCC4',
        }
        transitionDuration: {
          '300': '300ms',
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="sliding-section w-screen mx-auto">
  <div class="w-full grid grid-cols-2 gap-5 md:gap-10">
    <div class="residential feature-image">
      <img class="object-cover overflow-x-visible" src="https://danverstg.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/img4.jpg" alt="Residential" />
      <h3 class="hid-text-com text-right syne-font pt-4">Multi-Family</h3>
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 max-md:pl-5 max-md:w-[70%] ml-auto">
        <div class="hidden-button flex items-center justify-center max-md:order-2 max-md:mt-5"><a href="#" class="more-button work-sans-medium">learn more</a></div>
        <div class="max-md:order-1">
          <p class="hid-text-com text-right work-sans-light pt-4">See our wide variety of cabinet types and styles and how they can accommodate all of your outdoor kitchen needs</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="commercial">
      <img class="object-cover overflow-x-visible" src="https://danverstg.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/img5.jpg" alt="Commercial" />
      <h3 class="hid-text-com text-left syne-font pt-4">Hospitality</h3>
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 max-md:pr-5 max-md:w-[70%]">
        <div class="hid-text-com hidden-text">
          <p class="hid-text2 text-left work-sans-light pt-4">See our wide variety of cabinet types and styles and how they can accommodate all of your outdoor kitchen needs</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden-button flex items-center justify-center max-md:mt-5"><a href="#" class="more-button work-sans-medium">learn more</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



